# How to kill a running process in Linux shell without the use of pkill and pgrep commands?

Tags: c++, c, linux, pid, kill

In short, I'm trying to kill a process in the middle of its run. For example, I have a binary file `test` which runs something similar like:

```
while (true) {
  // Do something
}
```

I'm calling this binary file via the `system()` function in C++ like so:

```
const char* cmd = "test";
system(cmd);
```

Now is there any way for me to kill the process without having to manually go into the Linux shell? I have been able to manually simulate this function by running `test`and then typing `ctrl+c` into the shell. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can call the `kill` API direct rather than using the shell built-in.  `man 2 kill`.  Run the process using `fork`/`exec` rather that `system()` and you get back its `PID`.

Comment: By the way, bad idea to call the binary `test` since that s the name of a system supplied binary and also the name of a standard shell built-in.

Comment: Try to avoid `system()` - too little control, too many potential security problems. Prefer the `exec` family of functions if you *have* to use something so low-level. Better would be `QProcess` or some similar high level object.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The 'kill' API requires for me to know the pid so how would I be able to get that information without the shell?

Comment: `getpid`, `getppid` etc.

Comment: @AndyJin:  I added an edit to my comment to use `fork`/`exec`, enter that into a search engine and you will find lots of examples.  But don't call your program `test` !

Comment: **Why** do you want to kill it? Must it only run for a given time? If so, start it with `timeout`. You could change the program so that it checks if a file called `STOP` exists on every iteration and if it exists, it deletes the file and exits - then the calling process, or you in the Terminal, can `touch/create STOP` and it'll exit.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233134/is-it-possible-a-kill-a-command-launched-using-system-api-in-c-if-not-any-alter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible a kill a command launched using system api in C? If not any alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233134/is-it-possible-a-kill-a-command-launched-using-system-api-in-c-if-not-any-alter)